# I can't publish to a Facebook user's wall even though I have the publish_stream permission

Tags: android, facebook, desktop

I cannot post to Facebook through my desktop applicationsand get the following error.

> {"error":{"message":"(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id.","type":"OAuthException"}}

I use the Facebook Android SDK for logging in and getting the access token, and use the access token in a desktop application to get the friends list and to post messages to the user.

I can get the user's profile and list of friends, but I can't publish to his wall.

a. I have the `publish_stream` permission and `offline_access` permission
b. I obtain an access token after obtaining the code for application authentication as specified in the Facebook documentation

The URL I use to obtain the access token is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=CODE
```

The response is the following.

```
access_token=AAACPTk3uFT8BAKkB8labokDgYasskvBrlxXwTJYInomZAoizBRwk8XjZCQU7okD5Pt1pvxS02PulJOOZBlnHvVeisY6GJkfpk1Hf2GyhQRS3nf6FeRn&expires=6422
```

This shows that there is no exception thrown by Facebook.

However, I doubt that the access token I get from Facebook is invalid, since it is not similar to that shown in the example on the Facebook developers authentication guide.

In *[Facebook Graph API — getting access tokens](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/)*, Ben Biddington points out that the access token must also contain session information. According to him and the Facebook documentation, the token seems to be too short and is thus missing infomation.

How do I get an access token which will allow me to publish posts on a user's wall?

Answer (score 0):

You should recheck and show the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) which you use to request permission. Your access token has an expiry time, which seems unusual for an offline-access permission.

Comment: Thanks-Yes you are right. I do not ask for offline_access. I added that to the permissions and it still gives me the same error. I use a two step process-first i obtain the code after logging in, and then pass the code to the second step. I tested the url in a browser window. Any changes to client secret, code or app id result in error. If all three are ok, I get a response like access_token=AAACPTk3uFT8BAFrQewLehS8mZAvL7K3ZCm4Kg1YXF9dQP0YJERta2j1YBlOWXdxGZAV6HXBjogG2YHSldCOiqaomhlFMocQRJL0WVdpRAZDZD

Comment: The first step url is https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&client_id=157566477669695&scope=read_stream%2Cpublish_stream%2Coffline_access%2Cemail%2Cuser_work_history%2Cuser_about_me&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess . The second step url is https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=CODE

Comment: @user998556: about Ben Bidding post: I once seen the access token like his post, but it seems that FB change the format of access token. Now the access token is only a string.

Comment: @user998556: I have tried to get new access token(publish_stream &  offline_access) again, it's the same of yours (in format). Publishing stream is ok, too. I guess your problem is about the appId transfered to FB, is it in correct format?